# Https server response error

Tags: node.js, https

I'm developing a program that requires a https server and I also created the apropiate certificates. My problem start when I create the https server this way:

```
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200);
res.end('Open ssl running');
}).listen(8080);
```

I don't want to response a simple text, what I want is to send my static folder located in public directory where are the controllers, htmls and so on.

I also tried to send directly the path.join(__dirname, 'public') but it does not work.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Then use the express static middleware or some middleware like it.

Comment: to handle `ssl` consider using `nginx`

Comment: @zero298 Up in my code I have app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Delete the callback and:

```
    https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Started!');
});
```

Where options are the keys and app the Express app. Also the express middleware for send the static code.